# How to create tableview with curved frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibezierpath

Does anybody know how to create an UITableView with a curved frame, like MacOS downloads (in Dock panel) on iOS?

[image]

I tried to use for this the UIBezierPath class, but unfortunally I didn't succeed. For example I did this:

```
_tableView = [[TVCurveTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.view.frame.size.height - 130, 70, 160)];
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10, self.view.frame.size.height - 10)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40, (self.view.frame.size.height-10) - 160)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(110, (self.view.frame.size.height-10) - 160)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(80, (self.view.frame.size.height-10))];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, (self.view.frame.size.height-10))];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 2;
CAShapeLayer *shapeView = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shapeView setPath:bezierPath.CGPath];
    shapeView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[_tableView.layer addSublayer:shapeView];
```

Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: you can set background image as curved image for getting look like the you want

Answer (score 2):

My `COBezierTableView` does something similar though not with the tilting of the cells. That would be a nice thing to have as a option though, so maybe I´ll look into it. Fell tree also to deliver a pullrequest yourself if you find a sollution. ;-)

https://github.com/knutigro/COBezierTableView

Comment: Excuse me, and do you have your COBezierTableView wrote by Objective-C?

Comment: No, not at the moment. I did it as an excercise in learning Swift but its not a lot of code so it should't be to hard to translate it though.